Formatting seed for PDA
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(message: String)]
pub struct CreateImmortaliseMeAccount<'info> {
    // Account for creating an ImmortaliseMe account
    #[account(
        init,
        space= DISCRIMINATOR + ImmortaliseMeAccount::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds= [user.key().as_ref(), &message.as_bytes()[0..30]],
        bump,
        payer= user,
    )]
    message_account: Account<'info, ImmortaliseMeAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    user: Signer<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    // Account for creating a user's history account
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        space= DISCRIMINATOR + UserHistory::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [user.key().as_ref(), "history_account".as_bytes()],
        bump

    )]
    history_account: Account<'info, UserHistory>,
}

I need to cut the message down to <=32 bytes so it complies with the max 32 byte size per seed for a pda. But, Anchor (Or Solana) does not like recieving the seed in this format '&message.as_bytes()[0..30]'. Can anyone recognize the issue or suggest a solution please? You can assume the message will always be 32+ bytes in size.

Be sure to give the specific error you're seeing, it's tough to debug without that.
